# UnknownHostException: email.us-west-1.amazonaws.com with Amazon SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot

Writing a trivial Spring Boot app that uses Amazon Simple Email Service (SES). The sending fails with an UnknownHostException regarding the us-west-1 endpoint.

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: email.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1280)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
at com.amazonaws.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:27)
at com.amazonaws.http.DelegatingDnsResolver.resolve(DelegatingDnsResolver.java:38)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:112)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76)
at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy49.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1181)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1030)
... 93 more
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

US-WEST-1 does not have an SES endpoint address, nor has it ever.

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/regions.html#region-endpoints), it seems that SES is not available in us-west-1 anymore! Can't ping the endpoint as expected.