# Credential should be scoped to a valid region, not 'us-west-1' using AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services

Trying a send an email using SES using the us-west-2 service endpoint. My account is in us-west-1 so I specified that as the signing region:

```
    AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder builder 
         = AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard();
    builder.setEndpointConfiguration
        (new EndpointConfiguration("email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com", "us-west-1"));
```

I am getting this error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceException: Credential should be scoped to a valid region, not 'us-west-1'. (Service: AmazonSimpleEmailService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch;
```

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT**
Note that the signing region (where my account is) is us-west-1, whereas the endpoint is in us-west-2 as it should be. Could there be something I need to do in the AWS console first, like validate an email or something?

Comment: us-west-1 does not have SES  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ses_region

Comment: i dont think you need setEndpointConfiguration, just setRegion("us-west-2")

Comment: Please don't post essentially [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43132685/1695906) again, one hour after you already posted it.  Or [two hours](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43132192/1695906).  These are all extremely similar.

Comment: Michael, it is not the same question. Read again. I am using us-west-2 and still getting the error.

Comment: Guys, us-west-1 is the signing region not the endpoint.

Comment: I was facing this issue for the IAM GetUser call and I think for Global AWS services, the default region `us-east-1` needs to be used. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76286133/12326605

Answer (score 2):

It simply looks like you can't use one region with endpoint of another region.